# How to permute two columns of a tibble depending on the value of a third column?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following tibble:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(v1 = c(1,-1,1), min = c(2,3,4), max = c(4,5,6))
```

Which gives me:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
     v1   min   max
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2     4
2    -1     3     5
3     1     4     6
```

I want to permute the value of `min` with `max` if the value of `v1` is `-1`. That is the case of the second row (I want to get min=5 and max=3) . I want to do it using `dplyr`. I know that I have to use a third temporary variable but I can't do it in `dplyr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way *within* `dplyr` -

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
    min2 = min, 
    min = ifelse(v1 == -1, max, min), 
    max = ifelse(v1 == -1, min2, max), 
    min2 = NULL
  )

# A tibble: 3 x 3
     v1   min   max
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2     4
2    -1     5     3
3     1     4     6
```

Answer (score 3):

An easier option in `base R` is to create a logical index based on 'v1' and then assign by flipping the columns in the `rhs` and `lhs` expression of assignment

```
i1 <- df$v1 == -1
df[i1, c("min", "max")]  <- df[i1, c("max", "min")]
df
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#     v1   min   max
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     2     4
#2    -1     5     3
#3     1     4     6
```

---

An option using `filter/bind_rows` would be

```
df %>% 
   filter(v1 == -1) %>% 
   rename_all(~ c("v1", "max", "min")) %>% 
   bind_rows(df %>%
              filter(v1 != -1))
```

Comment: Yes, but you are not using `dplyr`.

Comment: @sbac Added a tidyverse option

Comment: Very interesting answer but you have permuted the values based on the opposite value of v1.

Comment: @sbac  I thinkj you missed the column name switch `%>% select(names(df))`

Comment: I can't see it.

Answer (score 2):

With `base`(idea about replacing the max borrowed from @akrun 's answer):

```
  within(df,{ min<-ifelse(v1==1,min,max)
        max <- ifelse(df$v1==-1,df$min,df$max)
        })
A tibble: 3 x 3
     v1   min   max
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2     4
2    -1     5     3
3     1     4     6
```

Comment: You got 5,5 in line 3 instead of 5,3.